# Why cloned project created with vue-cli-3 doesn't recognise '@' as path?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli-3

So, I am in the situation where I created a new Vue project with vue-cli-3. I have worked on it for several weeks.

I have decided to switch to my laptop from desktop as I will be travelling. So I pushed to repo on my desktop and now on my laptop I did `git clone` the project and used `npm install`.

Now, when I run `npm serve` == `vue-cli-service serve` I get error message that project doesn't recognise modules starting with `@` for example `import movements from '@/data/movements'`.

I have tried the same process with my work laptop and everything worked fine. Did I miss something during cloning from current repo or what happened? Why is that happening please?

I found that you can use `vue.config.js` and just rewrite the Webpack config (which helps) but why do I need to rewrite config when working on project from different computer?

This is my `.gitignore` file, I don't think it blocks any important files.

```
.DS_Store
node_modules
/dist

# local env files
.env.local
.env.*.local

# Log files
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# Editor directories and files
.idea
.vscode
*.suo
*.ntvs*
*.njsproj
*.sln
*.sw*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: There was nothing wrong with '@' but git screwed up my filenames.

Somehow my cloned project had `movements.js` with small m even though I have renamed it to capital M `Movements.js` before committing and pushing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#url-transform-rules) of the new version, `@` points to the `src` directory in templates only.

> If the URL starts with `@`, it's also interpreted as a module request. This is useful because Vue CLI by default aliases `@` to `<projectRoot>/src`. **(templates only)**

What you can try is to remove the `^` character from your `package.json` file to go back to the previous version of `vue` and then do `npm install` again. Hope that works.